# Focus event for button doesn't fire on iPad

Tags: javascript, html, ios, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-popover

I want to add a bootstrap popover to my site. It should show up, when the user pushes a button by using the focus event. This works on the Desktop, but not on the iPad. It seems like Safari on iOS doesn't raise the focus event for buttons altogether.

As a workaround, I replaced the button with an a tag. This does work, but gives some other issues like a lack of the disabled state without adding a specific class.

```
<a class="btn btn-outline-secondary" id="ap-btn-selectColor" data-toggle="popover" role="button">
    <i class="fa" style="background-color: rgb(140, 181, 255); width: 16px" id="ap-fgColorSelection">&nbsp;</i>
</a>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" id="ap-btn-selectBorderColor" data-toggle="popover">
    <i class="fa" style="background-color: rgb(0, 51, 142); width: 16px" id="ap-bdColorSelection">&nbsp;</i>
</button>
```

---

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    content: function () {
        return $someElement;
    },
    placement: 'auto',
    html: true,
    trigger: 'focus'
});
```

In my example, the popover works for the first element, but not for the second.

Is there a way to enable the focus event for buttons on iOS?

Comment: Do you mean safari by iOS? Cuz iOS isn't a browser.

Comment: @IslamElshobokshyI Yes. Safari, iOS' default browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was quite simple. You simply can't use a `button` on an iOS device, because it doesn't have a focus event. Instead, you should use an `a` tag with `role="button"` and a valid `tabindex` setting.

```
<a role="button" id="ap-btn-selectBorderColor" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-toggle="popover" tabindex="1">
    <i class="fa" style="background-color: rgb(0, 51, 142); width: 16px" id="ap-bdColorSelection">&nbsp;</i>
</a>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use a click event?

Comment: The problem with the click event is, that you would have to implement your own routine to close the popover manually. By using the focus event, it automatically closes itself after the next click or touch event.